# What is the best way to realize `(->) ((->) a b)` as an applicative functor?

Tags: haskell, applicative

I'm working on Problem 19 in [Ninety-Nine Haskell Problems](https://wiki.haskell.org/H-99:_Ninety-Nine_Haskell_Problems), and I've encountered the following difficulty. The problem asks to "rotate a list N places to the left." This could easily be achieved in a pointed way, e.g.,

```hs
rotate :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
rotate xs n = drop n xs ++ take n xs
```

However, for my own edification and for the challenge, I'd like to implement this in a point-free way using applicative functors. For instance, one can eliminate *one* of the arguments by using the fact that `(->) [a]` is an `Applicative` functor and implement `rotate` as follows:

```hs
rotate :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
rotate n = (++) <$> drop n <*> take n
```

Ideally, one should be able to eliminate *both* arguments, and write it as

```hs
rotate :: [a] -> Int -> [a]
rotate :: (++) <$> drop <*> take
```

but this causes a type error. (I'm not sure exactly how the type are being inferred, but the problem seems to be coming from the fact that the inferred `Applicative` functor is `(->) Int` rather than `(->) ((->) Int [a])`.)

One way to solve this would be to manually implement `(->) ((->) a b)` as an instance of `Applicative`, and, in particular, set

```hs
<*> f g x y = f x y (g x y)
```

but it seems that there should be a cleaner way to do this inline. What is the "right" way to solve this problem?

Comment: For what its worth, [pointfree.io](http://pointfree.io) give `rotate = ap ((<*>) . ((++) <$>) . drop) take`.

Comment: You can always ask [pointfree](http://pointfree.io/) to do it for you. It uses `ap` instead of `<*>` but it's the same thing.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems to me that `(->) (-> a) b` is not even a valid type, because `(->)` expects first type argument of kind `*`, but `(-> a) :: * -> *`

Comment: Sorry, you're absolutely right. It should have been `(->) a (-> b)`. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @jgaeb `(->) a (-> b)` is also invalid (ill-kinded) since the second argument of `(->)` must have kind `*` but `(-> b)` has kind `* -> *`.

Comment: @chi Ok, I worked it out in ghci: the type should be `(->) ((->) a b)`. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's an "optimal" way of doing this without using the Applicative instance.

```
import Data.Semigroup
rotate = drop <> take
```

We can be explicit about the type `(<>)` is instantiated at

```
{-# Language ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# Language TypeApplications    #-}

rotate :: forall a. Int -> [a] -> [a]
rotate = (<>) @(Int -> [a] -> [a]) drop take
```

Resolved using these instances:

```
instance Semigroup b => Semigroup (a -> b)
instance                Semigroup [a]
```

Answer (score 8):

Two choices:

```
rotate = liftA2 (liftA2 (++)) drop take
rotate = getCompose (liftA2 (++) (Compose drop) (Compose take))
```

The latter becomes the former after inlining the instance method definitions for `Compose`'s `Applicative` instance.

You may revert to spelling your `liftA2`s with `(<$>)` and `(<*>)` if you prefer it, of course.

Comment: You can use curry and uncurry instead of getCompose and Compose. Not sure if it's more readable or less :)

Comment: For the first, I've grown rather accustomed to the phrasing `(liftA2 . liftA2) (++) drop take`.  It implies (correctly) that you can put as many `liftA2`s as you need to get an appropriate combinator.